# Proof of $A \setminus B= A$ st $A \subset B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Problem statement - $A \setminus B= A$ st $A \subset B$

I think this statement is wrong as by definition of difference of sets $A \setminus B$ should contain all the elements of set $A$ **which are not** in $B$.But if $A$ is a subset of $B$ then all the elements of set $A$ are in set $B$ by default so shouldn't the answer be null set?

Comment: by set(A)-set(B) you mean $A \setminus B$?

Comment: @rtybase yes I mean that

Comment: Suppose $x \in A\setminus B$. Then $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$ - which contradicts $A \subset B$.  So $A$ cannot contain any elements.

Comment: Then you are right $A\setminus B = \varnothing $

Comment: @rtybase today our prof wrote this theorem in class and I was just trying to prove this but I couldnt..I thought maybe I am wrong in understanding something

Comment: You already have a valid answer below ... $A=A\setminus B \Rightarrow A=\varnothing $

Comment: What is "st"?  Does it mean "such that"?  Would you translate you sentence?  Do you mean for A proper subset B, that A\B = A?  It does not, it is empty.

Comment: @Dev_123 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing, if $A = \emptyset$ then

$$A \setminus B = \emptyset \setminus B = \emptyset \subset B$$

Comment: I am asking for the general case of A and B

Comment: Isn't the problem set to find $A, B$ that satisfy that relation? You just proved that for any $B$, $A = \emptyset$ is the only one that works.

Comment: Just to clarify you are saying that set(A)-set(B) is null set for all B,A where A is the subset of B?

Comment: Yes. Suppose $A \subset B$; $A \setminus B = \{a \in A : a \not \in B\} = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\subset B$ we have that $$x\in A \implies x\in B$$

but $$\forall y\in A \setminus B\implies y\in A \quad\land \quad y\not\in B$$

than $A=\emptyset$